# How to customize ember-bootstrap components?

Tags: ember.js, bootstrap-4, ember-bootstrap

I'm new to learning Ember and it mostly makes sense except I'm having a bit of a problem with templating.

My model retrieves a record array and I want to display each record in a collapse-able bootstrap accordion. There is a native ember-bootstrap component ([BsAccordion](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/components/accordion)) that seems to make this super easy, but it includes some styling that I'd prefer not to use.

My template is simple and looks like this:

```
<BsAccordion as |list|>
  {{#each mail as |message|}}
    <list.item @value={{message.id}} @title="{{message.sender.firstName}} {{message.sender.lastName}}: {{message.subject}}">
      {{{message.content}}}
    </list.item>
  {{/each}}
</BsAccordion>
```

The problem I have is that it wraps each message in a div with class="card" and I do not wish to use bootstrap's card layout. How can I customize the component and prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `card` class name is applied in the `addon/components/bs4/bs-accordion/item.js` file. See [v3.0.0-rc.0](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/v3.0.0-rc.0/addon/components/bs4/bs-accordion/item.js#L4) and [master](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/8bd7c203e57698d1a2b5a980050784d900fcb6dc/addon/components/bs4/bs-accordion/item.js#L5).

To override this file, define a `app/components/bs-accordion/item.js` in your app and override with the same content as in the original file, but omitting the unwanted class.